# Adding a colorbar whose color corresponds to the different lines in an existing plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My dataset is in the form of :

```
Data[0] = [headValue,x0,x1,..xN]
Data[1] = [headValue_ya,ya0,ya1,..yaN] 
Data[2] = [headValue_yb,yb0,yb1,..ybN]
...
Data[n] = [headvalue_yz,yz0,yz1,..yzN]
```

I want to plot f(y*) =  x, so I can visualize all Lineplots in the same figure with different colors, each color determined by the headervalue_y*.

I also want to add a colorbar whose color matching the lines and therefore the header values, so we can link visually which header value leads to which behaviour.

Here is what I am aiming for :(Plot from Lacroix B, Letort G, Pitayu L, et al. Microtubule Dynamics Scale with Cell Size to Set Spindle Length and Assembly Timing. Dev Cell. 2018;45(4):496–511.e6. doi:10.1016/j.devcel.2018.04.022)

[image: plot from Lacroix et al.]

I have trouble adding the colorbar, I have tried to extract N colors from a colormap (N is my number of different headValues, or column -1) and then adding for each line plot the color corresponding here is my code to clarify:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Data = [['Time',0,0.33,..200],[0.269,4,4.005,...11],[0.362,4,3.999,...16.21],...[0.347,4,3.84,...15.8]]
headValues = [0.269,0.362,0.335,0.323,0.161,0.338,0.341,0.428,0.245,0.305,0.305,0.314,0.299,0.395,0.32,0.437,0.203,0.41,0.392,0.347]
# the differents headValues_y* of each column here in a list but also in Data
# with headValue[0] = Data[1][0], headValue[1] = Data[2][0] ...
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('rainbow') # I choose my colormap
rgba = [] # the color container
for value in headValues:
    rgba.append(cmap(value)) # so rgba will contain a different color for each headValue

fig, (ax,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1) # creating my figure and two axes to put the Lines and the colorbar
c = 0 # index for my colors
for i in range(1, len(Data)):
    ax.plot( Data[0][1:], Data[i][1:] , color = rgba[c])
    # Data[0][1:] is x, Data[i][1:] is y, and the color associated with Data[i][0]
    c +=  1


fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap= mpl.colors.ListedColormap(rgba)), cax=ax1, orientation='horizontal')   
# here I create my scalarMappable for my lineplot and with the previously selected colors 'rgba' 
plt.show()
```

The current result:

[image: Plot Result]

How to add the colorbar on the side or the bottom of the first axis ?

How to properly add a scale to this colorbar correspondig to different headValues ?

How to make the colorbar scale and colors match to the different lines on the plot with the link One color = One headValue ?

I have tried to work with scatterplot which are more convenient to use with scalarMappable but no solution allows me to do all these things at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. As the 'headValues' aren't sorted, nor equally spaced and one is even used twice, it is not fully clear what the most-desired result would be.

Some remarks:

- The standard way of creating a colorbar in matplotlib doesn't need a separate subplot. Matplotlib will reduce the existing plot a bit and put the colorbar next to it (or below for a vertical bar).
- Converting the 'headValues' to a numpy array allows for compact code, e.g. writing `rgba = cmap(headValues)` directly calculates the complete array.
- Calling cmap on unchanged values will map 0 to the lowest color and 1 to the highest color, so for values only between 0.16 and 0.44 they all will be mapped to quite similar colors. One approach is to create a [norm](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html) to map 0.16 to the lowest color and 0.44 to the highest. In code: `norm = plt.Normalize(headValues.min(), headValues.max())` and then calculate `rgba = cmap(norm(headValues))`.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

headValues = np.array([0.269, 0.362, 0.335, 0.323, 0.161, 0.338, 0.341, 0.428, 0.245, 0.305, 0.305, 0.314, 0.299, 0.395, 0.32, 0.437, 0.203, 0.41, 0.392, 0.347])
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 500)
# create Data similar to the data in the question
Data = [['Time'] + list(x)] + [[val] + list(np.sqrt(4 * x) * val + 4) for val in headValues]
headValues = np.array([d[0] for d in Data[1:]])

order = np.argsort(headValues)
inverse_order = np.argsort(order)

cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
rgba = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(headValues)))  # evenly spaced colors

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for i in range(1, len(Data)):
    ax.plot(Data[0][1:], Data[i][1:], color=rgba[inverse_order[i-1]])
    # Data[0][1:] is x, Data[i][1:] is y, and the color associated with Data[i-1][0]

cbar = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(rgba)), orientation='vertical',
                    ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, len(rgba) * 2 + 1)[1::2])
cbar.set_ticklabels(headValues[order])
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, the colors can be assigned using their position in the colormap, but without creating

```py
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
norm = plt.Normalize(headValues.min(), headValues.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for i in range(1, len(Data)):
    ax.plot(Data[0][1:], Data[i][1:], color=cmap(norm(Data[i][0])))
cbar = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
```

To get ticks for each of the 'headValues', these ticks can be set explicitly. As putting a label for each tick will result in overlapping text, labels that are too close to other labels can be replaced by an empty string:

```py
headValues.sort()
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), ticks=headValues)
cbar2.set_ticklabels([val if val < next - 0.007 else '' for val, next in zip(headValues[:-1], headValues[1:])] 
                     + [headValues[-1]])
```

At the left the result of the first approach (colors in segments), at the right the alternative colorbars (color depending on value):

[image: demo plots]